# Functions with a special property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, special-functions

I was working on a subject. I encountered to the following functions. I was wondering is there a name for such function or property. 
$$f: A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$\exists \varepsilon $ such that $\forall (x,y)\in A, \exists (x',y')\in A$ such that $(x,y)\neq(x',y')$ and $|f(x,y)-f(x',y')|< \varepsilon$.
 Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: This property isn't really _special_, in that almost all functions have it. The reverse is.

Comment: Whereever you want to use this property, I would recommend deriving it from a smaller class of functions (say differentiable functions, bounded functions or continuous functions with nice enough domains) and working with that class instead, as this property is not very useful on its own.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of functions satisfy your requirement. A least:

- Bounded ones
- Locally bounded ones
- Continuous ones

**I know that it doesn't unfortunately answer your question. But I don't know a special name for functions satisfying your criteria...**

Comment: If $A$ has infinite isolated points then there are continuous and locally bounded functions that don't have this property.

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples & s.harp thanks for your answers. Let $A\subset \mathbb{N}^2$ and $f=\sqrt{xy}$.

Comment: If $A\subset \mathbb{N}^2$ and $f=\sqrt{xy}$, then is there any name or special properties for these functions?